# CSS3 multi-column list

Tags: html, wordpress, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I've been using CSS3 multi-column for a few Wordpress sites now and one thing that I find excepteble but still something I want to know how to fix is that if I put a list(with sub items) in the collumns that it won't keep the structure of the list

To make myself clear this is the HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
   <li>
      List-item
      <ul>
         <li>Sub-list-item</li>
         <li>Sub-list-item</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      List-item
      <ul>
         <li>Sub-list-item</li>
         <li>Sub-list-item</li>
      </ul
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS would be:

```
div{
-webkit-column-count:3;   
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -ms-column-count:3;
    -o-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap:15px;   
    -moz-column-gap:15px;
    -ms-column-gap:15px;
    -o-column-gap:15px;
    column-gap:15px;
    columns:3;
}
```

And this is what you get:

[image]

This is nice because it makes it possible in Wordpress to show menu's like this.
But one thing that bugs me is that it places the Sub-list-items in the next column while the parent of that item is in the previous column.

Is this fixable?

Before anyone says: why don't you just make multiple lists and make your own columns(this was the suggestion when I asked the question how to do this) this is for a dynamic Wordpress menu so I have no controll over how many items are in the menu.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Making your parent `<li>` `display: inline-block;` seems to "fix" this:

**Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/DczVL/1/**

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul > li > ul >li {
    color: red;
}
div {
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -ms-column-count:3;
    -o-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap:15px;
    -moz-column-gap:15px;
    -ms-column-gap:15px;
    -o-column-gap:15px;
    column-gap:15px;
    columns:3;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>List-item
            <ul>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>List-item
            <ul>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li>List-item
            <ul>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
                <li>Sub-list-item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```