# CSS3 multiple column list

Tags: css

I have a specific problem with multiple column list with inline-block styles in Google Chrome. Basically the same situation as described over here [CSS3 multi-column list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536800/css3-multi-column-list). It works perfect in all browsers except Chrome. Here is the link to the code http://jsfiddle.net/DczVL/1/

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
ul > li > ul >li {
  color: red;
}
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -ms-column-count: 3;
  -o-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
  -ms-column-gap: 15px;
  -o-column-gap: 15px;
  column-gap: 15px;
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List-item
      <ul>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List-item
      <ul>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List-item
      <ul>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
        <li>Sub-list-item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the result I want to achieve. Second level list is grouped with his parent and stays in the same column.
[image]
No matter how many columns you set, it always shows only 2 columns.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the

```
    display:inline-block
```

from `ul > li` in css

Comment: If I remove inline-block I will loose the structure. I want the second level list to be grouped with the parent in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div > ul > li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DczVL/314/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.menu {
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -ms-column-count:3;
    -o-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
    columns:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      one
        <ul>
          <li>sub one</li>
          <li>sub two</li>
          <li>sub three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      two
        <ul>
          <li>sub one</li>
          <li>sub two</li>
          <li>sub three</li>
        </ul>      
    </li>
    <li>
      three
        <ul>
          <li>sub one</li>
          <li>sub two</li>
          <li>sub three</li>
        </ul>      
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But i find it better to use float, inline-block or something like that.

EDIT: Update from your post

```js
  computeMenuWidth();

  function computeMenuWidth() {
    var $menu = $('ul.footer-menu');
    var $menuItems = $menu.children('li');
    
    $menuItems.width( parseFloat(100 / $menuItems.length) + '%' );
    $menu.show();  
  }


$('.add').click(function() {
  $('ul.footer-menu')
     .append($('ul.footer-menu').children('li').first().clone());
  
  computeMenuWidth();
});

$('.remove').click(function() {
  $('ul.footer-menu').children('li').last().remove();
  computeMenuWidth();
});
```

```css
ul.footer-menu, ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.footer-menu {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -20px;
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

ul li ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

ul li ul li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}

ul li ul li, ul li ul li a {
  color: grey;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="clear:both; margin: 30px 0;">
  <button class="add">Add Column</button>
  <button class="remove">Remove Column</button>
</div>

<ul class="footer-menu">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="headline">IT</span></li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="headline">Software</span></li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul>
        <li><span class="headline">Software</span></li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
      </ul>      
    </li>  
  
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="headline">Grafik</span></li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
        <li>Beratung & Konzept</li>
      </ul>
      
      <ul>
        <li><span class="headline">Service</span></li>
        <li>Support</li>
        <li>Downloads</li>
      </ul>      
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the picture above. Your code only makes 3 columns which is OK but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @MilanD see me update, its an example how you can solve your issue without `colums`