# CSS UL is divided into three columns

Tags: css

There is one monolithic data block of the UL.
How to use CSS to split a list of UL with multiple LI LVL1 into three columns with the same height? 
Each LI has different heights.
The number of LI blocks is always different.

```
<div class="div_list">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list_li">...</li>
        <li class="list_li">...</li>
        <li class="list_li">...</li>
        <li class="list_li">
            <ul>
                <li class="list_li_lvl2">...</li>
                <li class="list_li_lvl2">...</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list_li">...</li>
        <li class="list_li">...</li>
        <li class="list_li">...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I'm close to the answer, but LVL2 goes to the next column.

**EDIT 2:** 
Solution found [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tmLepm4w/5/)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536800/css3-multi-column-list

Comment: it seems to me that this is what I need

Comment: @Alex Muravyov, checked, that example for some reason only 2 columns does

Comment: @soft87,  try adding more list items